# How do I handle this tricky MySQL query [Concatenate based on priority from same table]?

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Before diving into a Python script to do this for me, I am wondering if we can achieve this via a MySQL query alone?

I have a table with multiple records per ID. I want to concatenate the multiple values into one record and concatenate based on priority? Still with me?

A table might help :

```
ID Value Priority
1  AA    1
1  KK    3
1  CC    2 
2  AA    1
3  EE    4  
3  FF    5 
2  HH    6
```

Desired Output :

```
ID Concat_Value 
1  AA, CC, KK
2  AA, HH
3  EE, FF
```

Priority goes in an increasing order. Smaller the number, higher the priority.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy as pie.

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(`value` ORDER BY priority) as concat_value
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

If you want a space in the group_concat, you'll have to change the separator:

```
SELECT 
  id
  , GROUP_CONCAT(`value` ORDER BY priority SEPARATOR ', ') as concat_value
FROM table1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I knew the group concat but did not know the order by in group concat. This is by far the quickest SO answer I got! How do we get a space in group concat - say 1, 2 instead of 1,2 ?